# SQL Server : get latest date from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have two tables P and G and want to write a query that will get the latest date from table G and will not pull in duplicate client IDs:

Table P

[image: Table P]

Table G

[image: Table G]

I want to get this result from the query:

[image]

So far I have joined the tables, but unable get the result intended.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your JOIN look like?

Comment: Does G_ID relate to P_ID, or is that a coincidence? Why does the row for 7/15/2012 have INFO = Y?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your tables are related other than your column `ClientID`, but you would want to join the two tables on those columns:

```
select p.clientid,
       max(g.created_on) latest_created_on,
       max(p.info) as info
from tableP p
left join tableG g on p.ClientID = g.ClientID
group by p.clientid;
```

[<kbd>SQL Fiddle Demo</kbd>](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d47bf/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use OVER PARTITION to take the record with the most recent date for each ClientID.

In this case, I would write:

```
SELECT g.ClientID,
    g.created_on,
    g.INFO
FROM (
    SELECT ClientID
        created_on,
        INFO,
        row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY created_on DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM Table_G
    ) AS g
WHERE g.RowNum = 1
```

The subquery creates a table with all the columns you want, and the row_number() function assigns each record a row_number. PARTITION BY says what to group by, and ORDER BY says how to sort within that partition.

In this case, you want the record with the most recent date for each ClientID. We group by ClientID, sort by date to assign row numbers, and then in the main query, we select only the first row in each group, using WHERE g.RowNum = 1

[This is a guide for PostreSQL, but it's helped me understand OVER PARTITION.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/tutorial-window.html)